# I have an animated image sequence which plays in a loop. How do connect it to a button that toggles between play and pause?

Tags: javascript, image, sequence, pause

```js
var images = new Array()
images = [
 'images/1.svg',
 'images/2.svg',
 'images/3.svg',
 'images/4.svg',
 'images/5.svg',
 'images/6.svg',
 'images/7.svg',
 'images/8.svg',
 'images/9.svg',
 'images/10.svg',
 'images/11.svg',
 'images/12.svg',
 'images/13.svg',
 'images/14.svg',
 'images/15.svg',
 'images/16.svg',
 'images/17.svg',
 'images/18.svg',
 ];

setInterval("Animate()", 100);

var x = 0;

function Animate() {
  document.getElementById("img").src = images[x]
  x++;
  if (images.length == x) {
    x = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     <div class="main">
   
  <div class="main vid1">
      <img id="img1" src="cat2/1.svg">
      </div>
  
       <div class="main vid2">
      <img id="img2" src="cat2/1.svg">
      </div>
    
 
      
</div>

     
    <div class="navfooter"> 
    
    
    <button id="bt1"></button>
    <button id="bt2"></button>
    
           
        </div>

  

     <div class="hidden-images">
    <img src="cat/1.svg" />
    <img src="cat/2.svg" />
    <img src="cat/3.svg" />
    <img src="cat/4.svg" />
    <img src="cat/5.svg" />
    <img src="cat/6.svg" />
    <img src="cat/7.svg" />
    <img src="cat/8.svg" />
    <img src="cat/9.svg" />
    <img src="cat/10.svg" />
    <img src="cat/11.svg" />
    <img src="cat/12.svg" />
    <img src="cat/13.svg" />
    <img src="cat/14.svg" />
    <img src="cat/15.svg" />
    <img src="cat/16.svg" />
    <img src="cat/17.svg" />
    <img src="cat/18.svg" />
    
</div>  
    

 </div>
<script>




const
  imgElm  = document.getElementById('img1')
, btOnOff = document.getElementById('bt1')
, images  = 
  [ 'cat/1.svg',  'cat/2.svg',  'cat/3.svg',  'cat/4.svg'
  , 'cat/5.svg',  'cat/6.svg',  'cat/7.svg',  'cat/8.svg'
  , 'cat/9.svg',  'cat/10.svg', 'cat/11.svg', 'cat/12.svg'
  , 'cat/13.svg', 'cat/14.svg', 'cat/15.svg', 'cat/16.svg'
  , 'cat/17.svg', 'cat/18.svg'
  ];



images.next       = 1;
images.refintv    = 0;
images.delay      = 100;

btOnOff.onclick   = startLoop;

function startLoop()
  {
  newImage();    // immediate changing on click

  
  btOnOff.onclick     = stopLoop;
  
  images.refintv = setInterval( newImage, images.delay);
  
  function newImage()
    {
    imgElm.src  = images[images.next];
    images.next = ++images.next % images.length;
    }
  }

function stopLoop()
  {
  clearInterval(images.refintv);
  btOnOff.onclick     = startLoop;
  }

var button = document.getElementById("bt1");
var audio = document.getElementById("player");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(audio.paused){
    audio.play();
    audio.loop= true;
  
  } else {
    audio.pause();
   
  }
   
  
});
 
  
</script>
```

Comment: now the only problem is I want to have 2 image sequences with 2 buttons for each image sequence but I tried to just double the code but it didn't work.

Comment: Is the above code the solution to the question asked here?

Answer (score 0):

This should help out. There's many ways you could organize and optimize this but this should give you a place to start.

```
<body>
    
<img src="images/1.svg">

<button onclick="toggle()">Play / Pause</button>

<script type="">

let
    loop,
    index = 0,
    images = [
    "images/1.svg", "images/2.svg", "images/3.svg", "images/4.svg", "images/5.svg", "images/6.svg", "images/7.svg", "images/8.svg", 
    "images/9.svg", "images/10.svg", "images/11.svg", "images/12.svg", "images/13.svg", "images/14.svg", "images/15.svg", "images/16.svg", 
    "images/17.svg", "images/18.svg"
];

function startLoop() {
    loop = setInterval(() => {
        document.querySelector('img').src = images[index];
        index++;
        // Loop images array
        if (index % images.length === 0) {
            index = 0;
        }
    }, 100);
}

function toggle() {
    if (loop) {
        clearInterval(loop);
        loop = null;
    } else {
        startLoop();
    }
}

startLoop();

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: this is great! How would I sync an audio file with this so that when you click the same button it pauses and plays a sound file in sync with the image sequence frame by frame or the exact length of the images in the array?

Comment: Also I want the image sequence along with the audio to start out as paused. And the sound needs to loop just like the image sequence.

Answer (score 0):

something more elaborate...

```js
const
  imgElm  = document.getElementById('img-id')
, btOnOff = document.getElementById('bt-start-stop')
, images  = [ 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22 ]
  ;
 
images.next       = 1;
images.refintv    = 0;
images.delay      = 1000;

btOnOff.onclick   = startLoop;

function startLoop()
  {
  newImage();    // immediate changing on click

  btOnOff.textContent = 'stop';
  btOnOff.onclick     = stopLoop;
  
  images.refintv = setInterval( newImage, images.delay);
  
  function newImage()
    {
    imgElm.src  = `https://picsum.photos/id/${images[images.next]}/300/200`;
    images.next = ++images.next % images.length;
    }
  }

function stopLoop()
  {
  clearInterval(images.refintv);
  btOnOff.textContent = 'start';
  btOnOff.onclick     = startLoop;
  }
```

```html
<button id="bt-start-stop">start</button>
<br><br>
<img id="img-id" src="https://picsum.photos/id/14/300/200" >
```

> with your actual code it should be:

full JS CODE

```
const
  imgElm  = document.getElementById('img-id')
, btOnOff = document.getElementById('bt-start-stop')
, images  = 
  [ 'images/1.svg',  'images/2.svg',  'images/3.svg',  'images/4.svg'
  , 'images/5.svg',  'images/6.svg',  'images/7.svg',  'images/8.svg'
  , 'images/9.svg',  'images/10.svg', 'images/11.svg', 'images/12.svg'
  , 'images/13.svg', 'images/14.svg', 'images/15.svg', 'images/16.svg'
  , 'images/17.svg', 'images/18.svg'
  ];
images.next       = 1;
images.refintv    = 0;
images.delay      = 1000;

btOnOff.onclick   = startLoop;

function startLoop()
  {
  newImage();    // immediate changing on click

  btOnOff.textContent = 'stop';
  btOnOff.onclick     = stopLoop;
  
  images.refintv = setInterval( newImage, images.delay);
  
  function newImage()
    {
    imgElm.src  = images[images.next];
    images.next = ++images.next % images.length;
    }
  }

function stopLoop()
  {
  clearInterval(images.refintv);
  btOnOff.textContent = 'start';
  btOnOff.onclick     = startLoop;
  }
```

full HTML CODE

```HTML
<button id="bt-start-stop">start</button>
<br><br>
<img id="img-id" src="images/1.svg" >
```

Comment: I can't get it to work with my pictures because I don't know how to add the src link correctly.

Comment: imgElm.src  = `https://picsum.photos/id/${images[images.next]}/300/200`;

Comment: how do you do this for internal folder files?

Comment: @Ammon this is a Template literals , with backQuotes  instead of quotes, and `${ xx }` where xx is a js variable. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: now it only plays one image at a time when you press the button.

Comment: @Ammon I have updated my answer  again ,  with full code.

Comment: I am trying to play audio in sync with the image sequence so that when you click the button the audio file plays and pauses with the images sequence so that even if the image sequence freezes up it will still be in sync frame by frame. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Ammon  sorry, I don't know anything about the use of soundtracks. but if it's something like a play() / pause() you can directly place each of these respectively at the beginning of the two functions startLoop() and stopLoop() ?

Comment: now the only problem is I want to have 2 image sequences with 2 buttons for each image sequence but I tried to just double the code but it didn't work.

Comment: I posted the new code down below which plays both the image sequence in a loop and a sound file in a loop with one button.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you...

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div.LoopImgs ')
  .forEach( div =>
  {
  let btOnOff = div.querySelector('button')
    , images  = div.querySelectorAll('img')
    , showed  = 0
    , refintv = 0
    , nextImg =()=> {
      images[showed].classList.remove('show');
      showed = ++showed % images.length;
      images[showed].classList.add('show');
      };
  btOnOff.onclick = (e) =>
    {
    if (btOnOff.classList.toggle('stop'))
      {
      nextImg();
      refintv = setInterval( nextImg, 1700 );
      }
    else
      {
      clearInterval(refintv);
      }
    }
  })
```

```css
div.LoopImgs                       { display: block; margin:1rem;         }
div.LoopImgs > button              { width: 4rem; margin: 0 0 .5rem 1rem; }
div.LoopImgs > button::before      { content: 'start'; }
div.LoopImgs > button.stop::before { content: 'stop';  }
div.LoopImgs > img                 { display : none;   }
div.LoopImgs > img.show            { display : block;  }
```

```html
<div class="LoopImgs">
  <button></button> 
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/14/300/200" class="show" >
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/15/300/200" >
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/16/300/200" >
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/17/300/200" >
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/18/300/200" >
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/19/300/200" >
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/21/300/200" >
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/22/300/200" >
</div>

<div class="LoopImgs">
  <button></button>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/30/300/200" class="show" >
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/31/300/200" >
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/32/300/200" >
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/33/300/200" >
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/34/300/200" >
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/35/300/200" >
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/37/300/200" >
</div>
```